# What is the difference between "The longest" and "Longest"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

hello guys i came across a question that is:

Mammoth Cave in Kentuck,Whic is ...... cave in the world,has 345 miles of subterranean passageways.

i reduced the answers to the longest and longest.But ı dont know what is the difference between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **cave** is a "countable noun", so

> Mammoth Cave in Kentucky, which is **the** longest cave in the world, has 345 miles of subterranean passageways.

Please see the Oxford Dictionary page about [Countable and uncountable nouns](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/countable-nouns)

Comment: actually, the correct answer is the other one. You must use the superlative, and that is not possible without "the".

Comment: Indeed, this does not answer the question. "The tallest trees in the world" is plural, and "the most polluted air in the world" is uncountable, and they both require the determiner. -1

Comment: @ColinFine true, I overlooked the superlative, but I never vote on other answers when I have submitted one. Otherwise there will be answer wars over which is the better answer, and frankly, is plain rude. Your answer speaks for itself.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of any contexts in which we would use a superlative like *longest* without "the" or another determiner like "my" (except in [Headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese), where articles are usually omitted).

Comment: please write a few words about forming the superlative, to make things most obvious. +1. I can add it myself if you agree.

Comment: The formation of the superlative is very basic English grammar, covered in any number of reference works. I don't think it appropriate to reproduce here.

Comment: I agree it is basic knowledge. However, the purpose would be to attract attention to the answer - which is definitely better than the chosen one. At least make the word "superlative" bold? :)